# Why is this eBay centric question being closed?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

The question with close votes found here: [How to overcome eBay CSS limits for auctions' pages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/how-to-overcome-ebay-css-limits-for-auctions-pages/2438) does it self no favours on first glance.

But there are two tangents of questions, which are useful to read, that this may fall under:

1. Tricks for dealing with inflexible/locked-up CMS's
2. Help on systems that you may have to update via an API (Amazon, Google Base, etc) from the website CMS and working around any inherent problems (especially maintaining design elements/branding)

Which leads to the question, why is this eBay centric question being closed? Or more importantly, if this question is beneficial how can it be rephrased to stop the knee jerk off topic response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not say it is being closed. The question has been up-voted twice and has received an answer that was subsequently up-voted.

Three more votes are needed to close the question at the time of this writing, or one moderator to determine that the question is off topic.

I think people may be objecting to the fact that it is talking about editing a page on e-bay, not on a web site that they maintain. That borders on going out of the realm of our topic as described in the FAQ.

However, it seemed like useful information (beyond the context of the question) would be provided in answers, and that the fact that it's an e-bay page (on its own) didn't blur the line clearly enough to warrant a super vote in my opinion.

If the question *is* closed, the OP should just consider editing it to take e-bay out of the question and give a meta example of 'something I just can't edit for whatever reason, need to work around it'.

Comment: "I think people may be objecting to the fact that it is talking about editing a page on e-bay, not on a web site that they maintain." That was the reason for my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

To me the question seems off topic because it talks specifically about how to solve a programming and style issue.  Those questions belong on Stack Overflow and the Style website.

That being said, there is some area of gray to it and it did receive two answers and both received up votes so to me there is no reason to push for it to be closed since it already has valid answers.

Also, just because a question received 2 votes to be closed doesn't mean that it will be closed.  It simply means some people think it isn't relevant to this site.

Hopefully at some point, the Stack Exchange team will allow moderators to transfer questions to the correct site.  I am not sure if they haven't had the time to do it yet or there is another reason against doing it currently, like we are in bating.